What could cause _all_ queries to slow down on a Postgres database for a limited period of time?

Consider the above graph of metrics. Each line represents the minimum duration of a parameterized database query (e.g. SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE foo = ? AND bar = ? would be represented as one line) over time.
Obviously, there could be many causes for a database query to be slow. But what could cause seemingly all database queries, across a variety of tables, to become slower? In this case the change in duration is on the order of 10-20 milliseconds.
The system in question:

The database's connections are pooled via PgBouncer on the server-side (no contention was observed via reported metrics)
The measured amount of free memory on the Postgres server didn't vary much during the window
The behavior was observed across a variety of tables and across a variety of statement types (SELECTs, INSERTs, UPDATEs, etc.)
No DDL statements were executed during the window shown.


Check the database and server activity. Please share the results, in plain text

Can you clarify what "database and server activity" means?

You can see what the database is doing, using pg_stat_activity. But the server could also be busy with something else, check top

Get detailed CPU statistics from that incident. Was the CPU overloaded? Was the disk overloaded (high iowait% values)?

The CPU was not overloaded per the metrics I have on hand.

Database loads are (rule of thumb here) HDD/SDD constrained - is/are there any other process(es) that could be eating into your disk usage for the period covered by the graph (scale on the y-axis is what exactly?) - i.e. a cron job or similar?

Do you use a VM ? Memory ballooning or unfixed cores can have a negative impact on a production server. Especially if the core or memory are overcommitted on the ESX...

@Vérace the server process is running on dedicated hardware on a cloud provider, so I don't think there'd be other things conflicting.

@SQLpro It's on the cloud but on single-tenant machine.
